# Compiling MSVC std lib with clang. Explicit template function specialization at class scope

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, template-specialization

I'm trying to compile the MSVC standard library using Clang. But it fails because the standard library uses explicit template function specialization at class scope.

This is a MS extension, and apparently not available in Clang.

Here's a simple example that compiles fine with MSVS, but not with Clang.

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {   
        foo((T)0, 0);
    }

    template<class T2>
    void foo(T2, void* p) {}

    template<>
    void foo<bool>(bool, void* p)
    {
        t = (T)p;
    }
    T t;
};

int main()
{
    A<bool> a;
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to get this feature to work when using Clang, so I can compile the MSVC standard library?

This is the compile error I get:

```
warning: explicit specialization of 'foo' within class scope is a Microsoft extension [-Wmicrosoft]
void foo<bool>(bool, void* p)

error: expected ';' after expression
                t = (T)p;
                       ^
                   ;
error: no member named 'T' in 'A<bool>'
                t = (T)p;
                     ^
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are you compiling MSVC's library with Clang?

Comment: from the comment it looks like Clang knows that this is a MS extension, because it only warns about it, but soemhow it does not get it right. Assuming `A<bool>` is just a bug here.

Comment: @Pubby, the MSVC stuff that doesn't compile is implemented in a header file that I include in my project. I compile with Clang because is gives a lot of very useful errors and warnings that MSVC doesn't even report.

Comment: I should also add that the MS std lib code that doesn't compile under Clang was added from MSVC10.0 to MSVC11.0 in this file:
VC\include\xlocnum
and probably other files too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have three possibilities:

1. Rewrite the MSVC library so it does not use that extension (could be fun, but time consuming...)
2. Fix that MS-extension in Clang (could be even more fun and time consuming...)
3. Do the sane thing: use each library with the compiler it was made for (how boring...)

---

**Update** from [this](https://github.com/jacob-carlborg/clang/blob/master/test/SemaTemplate/ms-function-specialization-class-scope.cpp) testing code for Clang I assume that it is already implemented, but it does not expect an explicit template parameter:

```
template<>
void foo(bool, void* p)
{
    t = (T)p;
}
```

Its probably a bug in Clang's implementation of that extension.

Comment: Its not fixing the MS-extension but probably implementing the extension altogether in clang :D

Comment: @RedX from the warning I supposed it's implemented, since if not it should be an error, not a warning. But see the update ;)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you will have to extend clang to support explicit specialization within class scope. I don't think there is any way around it, unless you want to modify the library.